# An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 142.250.27.109:587

Tags: c#

An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 142.250.27.109:587

Tried sending email from asp.net web forms website, i works perfect on localhost but its throwing this error when hosted on godaddy

An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions 142.250.27.109:587

i have tried different ports '587', '465' and '25' and different email providers outlook and google mail.

is there any other way i can get the app to send email?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/utW1v.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMlVt.png)

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre].

Comment: Does your hosting provider allow the outbound traffic?

Comment: I already put a screenshot of the code

Comment: Somehow you made a mistake and copy-pasted the first paragraph a second time

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: This is the error that I get on the page

Answer (score 0):

Most hosting provider don't allow sending e-mail over the common SMTP ports to prevent people from sending out spam.

Are you using GoDaddy's SMTP relay server for sending out e-mails?

If not, you will need to use the GoDaddy SMTP relay server. Here an overview of their SMTP relay servers:

| Data center | SMTP Relay Server |
| --- | --- |
| U.S. (West) | `dedrelay.secureserver.net` |
| U.S. (East) | `a2nlvphout-v01.shr.prod.iad2.secureserver.net` |
| Europe | `n1smtpout.europe.secureserver.net` |
| Asia | `sg2nlvphout-v01.shr.prod.sin2.secureserver.net` |

This and more information can be found on:
https://in.godaddy.com/help/send-form-mail-using-an-smtp-relay-server-953